# Simple word detector using MFCC

Tags: machine-learning, speech-recognition, mfcc

I am implementing a software for speech recognition using Mel Frequency Cepstrum Coefficients. In particular the system must recognize a single specified word. Since the audio file I get the MFCCs in a matrix with 12 rows(the MFCCs) and as many columns as the number of voice frames. I make the average of the rows, so I get a vector with only the 12 rows (the ith-row is the average of all ith-MFCCs of all frames). My question is how to train a classifier to detect the word? I have a training set with only positive samples, the MFCCs that i get from several audio file (several registration of the same word).

Answer (score 1):

> I make the average of the rows, so I get a vector with only the 12 rows (the ith-row is the average of all ith-MFCCs of all frames).

This is a very bad idea because you lose all information about the word, you need to analyze the whole mfcc sequence, not a part of it

> My question is how to train a classifier to detect the word?

The simple form would be a GMM classifier, you can check here:

http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/developing-an-isolated-word-recognition-system-in-matlab.html

In more complex form you need to learn more complex model like HMM. You can learn more about HMM from textbook like this one

[http://www.amazon.com/Fundamentals-Speech-Recognition-Lawrence-Rabiner/dp/0130151572](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130151572)

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. I got the MFCCs from the voice frames and I construct the gaussian mixture model through the matlab function gmdistribution. After that I test the model with a new audio. I get again the MFCCs from the new audio and with the posterior function I get the probability of each MFCCs. Now how can the system takes a decision about this probabilities?

Comment: You get probability for all words you are looking for and the word with highest probability is the answer. The link above says "The test speech is classified as the digit with the GMM that produces the maximum log-likelihood value."

Comment: Ok. Now I have a word and I want to know if it matches with the one that I used to construct the gaussian mixture model first. So I launch the posterior function with in input the MFCCs of that audio and I get the log likelihood value. I need to compare that value with a threshold to decide if that word matches with the original?

Comment: How can I get this threshold? I was thinking to use a clustering algorithm with two centroid, but the negative samples are few.

Comment: Sorry, I have another question. The result of posterior function is the negative logarithm of likelihood, if likelihood is in range [0,1], the nevative log is positive, but the function is discendent, it means that the best value is when the negative log likelihood is near 0. Is it right? Another question, do I have a gmm for each word to detect? So when I'll capture audio from microphone I'll compare the MFCCs with all the GMM that I and the result is the GMM that gives me the grater likelihood ?

Comment: You can get threshold on a random recording. The value for the likelihood is between 0 and 1. I answered your third question above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to say how many MFCCs are necessary to have good performance? I want to detect speech and speaker. Now I am using a 13 coefficients and I don't have bad performance, Now I am working to find a good threshold for reduce the misclassification of the negative samples, the system detects them as training word.